# Lightroom-style Black & White Conversion in Photoshop

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, photoshop, black-and-white

Until recently I did almost all my processing in Lightroom, but a combination of its increasingly poor performance and lack of tooling (luminance masks for example), has lead me back to giving Photoshop a much greater role. Although I do lens correction, global tone-mapping and capture sharpening in Lightroom, I then switch to Photoshop. I generally work towards a black and white image and prefer to do the conversion as late in the process as I can. This means I need to do it in Photoshop instead of Lightroom, but Photoshop's B & W adjustment layer doesn't feel as useful as Lightroom's which adds two extra channels - aqua and orange - to Photoshop's six.

Is there any way to replicate Lightroom's eight-channel approach in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "Channel Mixer" adjustment. (It's in the "Image" menu under the "Adjustments" submenu.) It allows you to choose the amount of red, green, and blue from the input to use to calculate the final value for each channel. If you select the "monochrome" checkbox it allows you to use the same output value for all 3 channels, creating grayscale. It also include a few presets specifically for black and white.

There's an "Orange" filter setting that should do something similar to having an orange filter on a film camera with black and white film. While there's not one for aqua, you would probably be able to create one by favoring the blue and green channels in the output. For example, a mix of 40% green, 40% blue and 20% red might give you something close.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Silver Effex](https://www.google.com/nikcollection/products/silver-efex-pro/). It may not have as many color sliders as LR, but the final effect looks usually less synthetic than my B&W attempts in LR or PS. I think it is a free download now.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know, Google no longer supports any of the Nik collection, so it will break any day now with an Adobe or OS update. Better to avoid relying on it.